# How to extract product's information from Amazon site web with Scrapy and Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract product's information from Amazon web site with Scrapy and Selenium.
The following source code connects to the Amazon website and then performs a search by the letter "A". 
Then I recovers the links of search result sets. But when I made a loop to go to each one of search results nothing happens (it just connects to the first result). 
Thank you for helping me to correct this code.

Source code "Spider"

```
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
    from time import sleep
    import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
    from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
    #from runner.items import RunnerItem
    from extraction.items import ProduitItem
    class RunnerSpider(CrawlSpider):
      name = 'products'
      allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
      start_urls = ['http://www.amazon.com']

      def __init__(self):
           self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

      def parse(self, response): 
        items = []       
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        recherche = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
        recherche.send_keys("A")
        recherche.submit()
        #time.sleep(2.5)

        # all search results links
        resultas = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="s-results-list-atf"]/li/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')

        for result in resultas:
          item = ProduitItem()
          lien = result
          lien.click()
          # exemple of data extracted 
          item['NOM'] = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@id="aiv-content-title"]').text()
          item['IMAGE'] = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dv-dp-left-content"]/div[1]/div/div/img/@src').text()
          items.append(item)

      self.driver.close()
      yield items
```

Source code "Item"

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import scrapy
    class ProduitItem(scrapy.Item):
       NOM = scrapy.Field()
       IMAGE = scrapy.Field()
```

Source code "piplines"

```
    from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
    class DuplicatesPipeline(object):
      def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen=set()
      def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
           raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s"%item)
        else:
           self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of the result site in your browser using developer tools (for example in Chrome) you can see that your code

```
resultas = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="s-results-list-atf"]/li/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')
```

returns only one element. This is because all the results are in the same `ul` block and you get the first `li` element.

You should get the `ul[@id="s-results-list-atf"]` element then iterate over every list item with `element.xpath('//li')` and then get the URL of the detail site. Alternatively you can skip the strolling through the `div`s and find the URL inside the `li` blocks with a `class` matching.

And you could get the data without Selenium too -- even if you want to search.

**Update**

The code above is for plain old Scrapy where you apply the `xpath` call on the response.
With Selenium it works a bit different because you get Selenium elements in return -- but on these you can apply the the `find_elements_by_xpath` on those elements in the list.

Comment: Thank you. Please, can you tell me how I can apply .xpath query to the result of self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(''). I get this error message when i try to do that : Element is not currently visible and so may not Stacktrace